# Program has no output (3 lines expected), no compilation or runtime errors

Tags: c, concatenation

The program is available here: http://ideone.com/P1c15J

Here's briefly what it does:

Declares a string `ptr`. Converts this pointers address to a little-endian address and stores those bytes in a `char[] adr`. Prints this out.

Then concatenate the strings `ptr` and `adr` into `badcode`, print `badcode`.

The program actually works if you take out the last two lines (concatenation and print badcode). There is expected output.

For some reason there is no compilation error, no runtime error but also no output when I try to concatenate and print out the string.

**EDIT:** I know the output I'm expecting will be garbled because the bytes contained in adr don't map to ASCII characters. That's not a problem for me at the moment. I'm interesting in getting the address bytes in the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t i;

    char badcode[500];

    char const *ptr = "This string's little endian memory address is: ";

    char adr[sizeof(void *) + 1];
    uintptr_t ptrAddress = (uintptr_t)ptr;

    printf("Pointer address is %p\n", ptr);
    printf("Converting to 0x");
    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(void *); ++i)
    {
        adr[i] = ptrAddress & 0xff;
        printf("%2.2X", (unsigned int)(unsigned char)adr[i]);
        ptrAddress >>= 8;
    }
    printf("\n");

    snprintf(badcode, sizeof badcode, "%s%s", ptr, adr);

    printf("\n%s", badcode);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: adr[sizeof(void*)]=0;

Comment: Sorry @qwr I'm not sure I get what you mean? Is adr nil? I don't think so at this point as the individual prints from the for loop show that adr is of length 4 and each index is set to a value.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: Well you written %s so adr should be null terminating.or sprintf it otherwise. And test with real compiler

Comment: Try this:  `snprintf(badcode, sizeof badcode, "%s%p", ptr, adr);`

Comment: Do you mean there is no output in the result of "http://ideone.com"?

Comment: I'm not looking for the mem address of adr I know I can print that with %p. What my program does is take the mem addr of ptr, convert that into little endian bytes and store that into adr. I expect adr[4] to contain ie = "\x12\x34\x56\x78". I would like to append those four bytes in adr to the char array badcode. I expect ASCII output to be garbled but at least demonstrate the bytes are there

Comment: I already told to you to test it with others. Assuming you have not got compiler. See this http://codepad.org

Comment: `Adr` is not a string, it is an array of bytes.  After you append the `'\0'`, it will be a string.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to print unterminated string `adr` with

```
snprintf(badcode, sizeof badcode, "%s%s", ptr, adr);
```

As suggested by @adr, add before the `printf()`

```
adr[sizeof(void*)]=0;
```

OR (assuming sizeof(void*) is 4)

```
snprintf(badcode, sizeof badcode, "%s%hh02X%hh02X%hh02X%hh02X", 
    ptr, adr[0], adr[1], adr[2], adr[3]);
```

---

OP expects `adr[4]` to contain something like "\x12\x34\x56\x78", but what `a[5]` contains is something like `'\x12'`, `'\x34`, `'\x56`, `'\x78`, `junk`. Since the last byte is not known to be `'\0'`, UB results.  When using `snprintf(..., "%s", adr)`, the `adr` needs to be `'\0'` terminated.